# How to select * order by user login?

Tags: mysql

[Ask] Please help, for example, there is a data

```
tbl_user
| Id | name |
| 1 | Bayu |
| 2 | Indra |
| 3 | Rangga |

tbl_data
| Id | userId | items |
| 1 | 1 | Knife |
| 2 | 3 | CD |
| 3 | 1 | Rose |
| 4 | 3 | HP |
| 5 | 2 | Honey |
| 6 | 1 | cups |
| 7 | 1 | Yarn |
| 8 | 2 | Shoes |
```

I want to sort by items table data is only logged user access
so for example when user Bayu logged in sorting results of the data is the top itself and of the data persists

```
userId | items |
1 | Yarn |
1 | cups |
1 | Knife |
1 | Rose |
2 | Honey |
2 | Shoes |
3 | CD |
3 | HP |
```

when Indra login the results of the sort:

```
userId | items |
2 | Honey |
2 | Shoes |
1 | Yarn |
1 | cups |
1 | Knife |
1 | Rose |
3 | CD |
3 | HP |
```

or when Rangga login

```
userId | items |
3 | CD |
3 | HP |
1 | Yarn |
1 | cups |
1 | Knife |
1 | Rose |
2 | Honey |
2 | Shoes |
```

How to query (MySQL) select it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select userId, items 
 from tbl_data 
 order by userId=:userId desc, userId asc;
```

For example if Indra logged in:

```
 select userId, items 
 from tbl_data 
 order by userId=2 desc, userId asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

imaging when a user login, there will be a $userID pass in on the page:

```
$sql = "
SELECT userId,items
FROM tbl_data
ORDER BY if (userID = $userId, 0, userId)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but this should do trick:

```
SELECT userID, items FROM tbl_data, tbl_user where userId=tbl_user.id AND tbl_user.name=CURRENT_USER()
UNION
SELECT userID, items FROM tbl_data, tbl_user WHERE userId<>tbl_user.id  AND tbl_user.name=CURRENT_USER();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to `userID` `order by` with logged in user and then order by other userId in ascending and descending order.

```
select userId, items 
from tbl_data 
order by FIELD(userId , $userId) desc, userId asc;
```